# gawk regexp does not match some input

Tags: awk

GNU Awk 5.1.1
cygwin

My regexp matches some inputs (Subject:, CC:, Date:) and doesn't allow leading spaces. The other part that bothers me is that I have two if...else statement. My guess is that any input must fall into one of these if...else statement, but, the unrecognized input (From:, CC:, Date:) does not.

I know it's something dumb but I can't figure out what it is.

What I am trying to do is to rearrange Thunderbird saved email text using gawk. A sample program and data are given below. Can anyone point out what I've done wrong?

```
---------------- Code ----------------

    #! /bin/gawk  -f
    {
       gsub(/\x00/, " ", "g");                       # replace regexp with " "
       if ($0 ~ /^[[:space:]]+$/) {                 # ignore blank line
          print "Recognized a blank line \"", $0, "\"";
       } else {
          if ($0 ~ /^[[:space:]]*(Subject|Date|CC|BCC|From|To):/) {
             print "Recognized input \"", $0. "\"";
             getline;
          } else {
             print "Did not recognize input \"",$0, "\"";
          }
       }
    }

---------------- Data ----------------
Subject:
From:
To:
CC:
BCC:
Date:
   Subject:
   From:
   To:
   CC:
   BCC:
   Date:

---------------- Output ----------------
Recognized input " Subject:"
Recognized input " To:"
Recognized input " BCC:"
Did not recognize input "    Subject: "
Did not recognize input "    From: "
Did not recognize input "    To: "
Did not recognize input "    CC: "
Did not recognize input "    BCC: "
Did not recognize input "    Date: "

---------------- Expected Output ----------------
Recognized input " Subject:"
Recognized input " From:"
Recognized input " To:"
Recognized input " CC:"
Recognized input " BCC:"
Recognized input " Date:"
Recognized input "    Subject:"
Recognized input "    From:"
Recognized input "    To:"
Recognized input "    CC:"
Recognized input "    BCC:"
Recognized input "    Date:"
```

Comment: Note you can't use POSIX character classes outside of bracket expressions. Never use `[:space:]*`, use `[[:space:]]*`

Comment: `gensub(/\x00/, " ", "g");` This is not how `gensub` is used: _Unlike `sub` and `gsub`, the modified string is returned as the result of the function and the original target string is not changed._ In that form use `gsub` instead.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Changed the bracketed expressions to '[[:space:]]' without any effect. Same input. Same output. I had tried this in the past.

Comment: @JamesBrown Thanks for pointing this out. Changes made

Comment: if you've made code changes and are still having issues ... update the question with the latest code changes, the (wrong) output generated by your (new) code, and the (correct) expected output

Comment: @markp-fuso All suggested code changes have been made without affecting the output. Thanks for suggesting that I include the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

As Wiktor has already commented on:

- replace `[:space:]` with `[[:space:]]`

Alternatively, using [GNU awk regex operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/GNU-Regexp-Operators.html) a few variations work for this particular data set:

- replace `^[:space:]*` with `\s*` (zero or more spaces)
- replace `^[:space:]*` with `\<` (word boundary)
- replace `^[:space:]*` with `\y` (word boundary)

These convert the 2nd `if` from this:

```
if ($0 ~ /^[:space:]*(Subject|Date|CC|BCC|From|To):/)
```

to one of these:

```
if ($0 ~ /^[[:space:]]*(Subject|Date|CC|BCC|From|To):/)
if ($0 ~ /\s*(Subject|Date|CC|BCC|From|To):/)
if ($0 ~ /\<(Subject|Date|CC|BCC|From|To):/)
if ($0 ~ /\y(Subject|Date|CC|BCC|From|To):/)
```

All of these generate:

```
Recognized input " Subject:"
Recognized input " To:"
Recognized input " BCC:"
Recognized input "    Subject:"
Recognized input "    To:"
Recognized input "    BCC:"
```

At this point we're missing the `From:`, `CC:` and `Date:` entries.  These lines are missing due to the misuse of the `getline` command.

`awk` implicilty performs a  `getline` on each pass through the file; running an explicit `getline` pulls the next line from the input and assigns to `$0` but, because nothing is done with the new `$0` (before returning to the beginning of the script and running an implicit `getline`) we effectively discard these lines.

After removing the `getline` the code generates:

```
Recognized input " Subject:"
Recognized input " From:"
Recognized input " To:"
Recognized input " CC:"
Recognized input " BCC:"
Recognized input " Date:"
Recognized input "    Subject:"
Recognized input "    From:"
Recognized input "    To:"
Recognized input "    CC:"
Recognized input "    BCC:"
Recognized input "    Date:"
```

Comment: All of your points are well taken and the result is that my self-image, though tarnished, is intact - and the code changes worked. (See, I told you it was dumb!) Thank you (all).

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your code, but the main issue is the use of the `getline` statement. This is the main reason why you skip every other line.

A cleanup of your code would look something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# replace NULL character (\x00) with " "
{ gsub(/\x00/, " ", "g"); }
(NF == 0) { print "Recognized a blank line \"", $0, "\""; next }
$1 ~ /^(Subject|Date|CC|BCC|From|To):/ { print "Recognized input \"" $0 "\""; next }
{ print "Did not recognize input \"",$0, "\""; }
```